# how to quit an iframe with click on a div?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a blog with different iframes, they are loaded by clicking on it. Now im searching for a possibillity to quit one iframe by clicking on the next.

Here is a snippet of my code, and here a link to the site it is for:
http://hallointer.net/

I hope someone has an idea.

```html
<iframe class="desktopframe" name="iframe_39" id="iframe_39"></iframe>
<a href="http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png" class="loadframe" target="iframe_39" onclick="on_iframe_load()">
   <div class="desktopframeclick">CLICK TO LOAD PAGE</div>
</a>


<iframe class="desktopframe" name="iframe_38" id="iframe_38"></iframe>
<a href="http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png" class="loadframe" target="iframe_38" onclick="on_iframe_load()">
   <div class="desktopframeclick">CLICK TO LOAD PAGE</div>
</a>

<iframe class="desktop2frame" name="iframe_37" id="iframe_37"></iframe>
<a href="http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png" class="loadframe" target="iframe_37" onclick="on_iframe_load()">
   <div class="desktop2frameclick">CLICK TO LOAD PAGE</div>
</a>
```

Comment: would wrapping the `iframe` in a `div`, hiding it work?

Comment: in this case it isn´t a solution, because it still sucks performance. i really need a way to quit them. but i hadn´t found a way to do that at all.

Comment: You can remove them with some javascript

Answer (score -1):

`on_iframe_load()` is called when you click on the `CLICK TO LOAD PAGE` div. This function hides all iframes and then shows the one associated with the clicked link.

Check **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vijaypancholi2626/3f4g05po/)**

```js
function on_iframe_load(iframeId) {
    // Hide all iframes
    var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('.desktopframe, .desktop2frame');
    iframes.forEach(function(iframe) {
      iframe.style.display = 'none';
    });

    // Show the clicked iframe
    var clickedIframe = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    if (clickedIframe) {
      clickedIframe.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
```

```css
.desktopframe, .desktop2frame {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="desktopframe" name="iframe_39" id="iframe_39"></iframe>
<a href="http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png" class="loadframe" target="iframe_39" onclick="on_iframe_load('iframe_39')">
   <div class="desktopframeclick">CLICK TO LOAD PAGE</div>
</a>


<iframe class="desktopframe" name="iframe_38" id="iframe_38"></iframe>
<a href="http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png" class="loadframe" target="iframe_38" onclick="on_iframe_load('iframe_38')">
   <div class="desktopframeclick">CLICK TO LOAD PAGE</div>
</a>

<iframe class="desktop2frame" name="iframe_37" id="iframe_37"></iframe>
<a href="http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png" class="loadframe" target="iframe_37" onclick="on_iframe_load('iframe_37')">
   <div class="desktop2frameclick">CLICK TO LOAD PAGE</div>
</a>
```